# Receiver (<MyQueryTableController: 0x9b7e9b0>) has no segue with identifier 'test''.......and more

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, segue, parse-platform

I know the title of my issue is similar to others, but I have looked at almost every other topic on this and nothing fixes my issue. Allow me to explain:

I have this happening when I click a button (in my class ViewController.m):

```
MyQueryTableController *myController = [[MyQueryTableController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

Now when I want to go to a different view from MyQueryTableController by clicking on a table cell I have this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"test" sender:self];
```

which brings us to this error: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'test''

I'm guessing this means that the myController is not on the storyboard or something, so it doesn't recognize the segue.

To fix this, I tried declaring myController like this:

```
MyQueryTableController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table"];
```

and pushing it the same way:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

When I do this, I get this error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "wOE-Bf-310-view-jaT-Nk-xnR" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

MyQueryTableController is a subclass of PFQueryTableViewController, which I believe is a subclass of UITableViewController. I'm using Parse for my backend.

Sorry if this is all confusing, but does anyone think they could make some sense out of this?

Thanks

EDIT: Ok, so I tried to make everything go through the storyboard instead of the nav controller, and I get this error now: [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "wOE-Bf-310-view-jaT-Nk-xnR" nib but didn't get a UITableView.

EDIT AGAIN: Hey guys, I figured out the issue. I had to change initWithStyle to initWithCoder...

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?? This is really mind-boggling and I can't really do anything else with the project without getting past this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the identifier on your segue to "test". If not, click on the identifier and add the identifier to it as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: hmm. may be some problem with segue connection. try re-adding the segue.

Comment: I have already tried that. There is no issue with the segue. I think it has to do with the way I'm declaring the view controller...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 2 years late, but since was the first one to pop up when I googled it i'm still gonna answer it. I got the same problem but solved it with a few clicks.

Go to Product => Clean (Shift+CMD+K). This solved it for me.